# image growing animation in android

Tags: android

Help me in android animation

first want to show my thumbnile image on screen and clicking on it, i want to show my full image with animation. just like the thumbnile image is growing to show actual image to occupies the whole screen.

please help out.

Comment: See this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/ScaleAnimation.html

Comment: Here is a tutorial http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=343

Answer (score 4):

First set your image lenth and height 50dip.. and apply this animation on image..

```
<scale
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:fromXScale=".1"
android:fromYScale=".1"
android:toXScale="20.0"
android:toYScale="20.0"
android:duration="1000" />
```